# Orbot app is constantly starting and shuting down

Tags: orbot

My phone is rooted so I have given root access to the app.
Then, when I press to start orbot, it says, orbot is starting, then comes NOTICE: Finished bootstrapped 10% orbot is finishing handshake with directory.

Then it comes, orbot is sending HALT Signal to the process, then orbot is deactivated.

I can't surf the net....
.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the app cache - it's a glitch happening on app upgrade and, sometimes, on system upgrade/reconfiguration.